# PHP | how to find tag name of given content of xml

Tags: php, xml, tags

I want to build a function like this:

```
function getTagNameOfGivenContent($content){...}
```

And this is an example for xml:

```
<w:r>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial" />
        <w:sz w:val="18" />
        <w:szCs w:val="18" />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>tfInvLineTaxCode</w:t>
</w:r>
```

So when I call the function like this

```
getTagNameOfGivenContent('tfInvLineTaxCode')
```

It will return

```
<w:t>tfInvLineTaxCode</w:t>
```

Can anyone tell me how to build this function?

Comment: You may want to look into XPath queries and PHP's DOMXPath class. I can never remember the XPath syntax for this particular thing, but you should be able to look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that ...

1. loads the XML into a [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and then ...
2. creates a [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) object on which to ...
3. run an [XPath query](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) to find the first node with matching [text](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Text-Nodes) content.
4. If found, the markup for that node is returned. If not, *null* is returned.

Code:

```
$source = <<<EOX
<root xmlns:w="whatever">
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="18" />
            <w:szCs w:val="18" />
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>tfInvLineTaxCode</w:t>
    </w:r>
</root>
EOX;

// Create/load a DOMDocument and a DOMXPath instance 
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadXML($source);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

function getTagNameOfGivenContent($content)
{
    // Query XPath instance for first node with a text that matches $content
    global $xpath;
    $tags = $xpath->query('//*[text()="' . $content .'"][1]');

    if ($tags->length > 0) {
        // We got a match
        $tag = $tags->item(0);
        return $tag->ownerDocument->saveXML($tag);
    }

    // No match
    return null;
}

// Try it out
echo getTagNameOfGivenContent('tfInvLineTaxCode');
```

Output:

```
<w:t>tfInvLineTaxCode</w:t>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this:

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();

$dom->loadXML($xml_doc);

$script = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script');
```

More Info -> http://php.net/manual/es/class.domdocument.php

I hope it helps.

Comment: No, I don't think this will work for my case, anyway, thanks for your respond

Comment: True, I misunderstanding. You are looking for content, not tag name. Sorry

Comment: It's ok pabgaran, if you know anyone can help me, please tell them I need their help. :)